# Сделать запрс к серверу в jQuery select2

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, select2

Я хотел бы узнать, как отправляются запросы к серверу используя `jQuery`, `select2` и `ajax`, а также как полученный ответ помещается в выпадающий список в `select2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот [здесь](http://select2.github.io/select2/) вы можете найти пример кода выполняющий запрос к серверу для получения данных.

```js
    $("#e6").select2({
        placeholder: "Search for a repository",
        minimumInputLength: 1,
        ajax: { // instead of writing the function to execute the request we use Select2's convenient helper
            url: "https://api.github.com/search/repositories",
            dataType: 'json',
            quietMillis: 250,
            data: function (term, page) {
                return {
                    q: term, // search term
                };
            },
            results: function (data, page) { // parse the results into the format expected by Select2.
                // since we are using custom formatting functions we do not need to alter the remote JSON data
                return { results: data.items };
            },
            cache: true
        },
        initSelection: function(element, callback) {
            // the input tag has a value attribute preloaded that points to a preselected repository's id
            // this function resolves that id attribute to an object that select2 can render
            // using its formatResult renderer - that way the repository name is shown preselected
            var id = $(element).val();
            if (id !== "") {
                $.ajax("https://api.github.com/repositories/" + id, {
                    dataType: "json"
                }).done(function(data) { callback(data); });
            }
        },
        formatResult: repoFormatResult, // omitted for brevity, see the source of this page
        formatSelection: repoFormatSelection,  // omitted for brevity, see the source of this page
        dropdownCssClass: "bigdrop", // apply css that makes the dropdown taller
        escapeMarkup: function (m) { return m; } // we do not want to escape markup since we are displaying html in results
    });
    
       function repoFormatResult(repo) {
      var markup = '<div class="row-fluid">' +
         '<div class="span2"><img src="' + repo.owner.avatar_url + '" /></div>' +
         '<div class="span10">' +
            '<div class="row-fluid">' +
               '<div class="span6">' + repo.full_name + '</div>' +
               '<div class="span3"><i class="fa fa-code-fork"></i> ' + repo.forks_count + '</div>' +
               '<div class="span3"><i class="fa fa-star"></i> ' + repo.stargazers_count + '</div>' +
            '</div>';

      if (repo.description) {
         markup += '<div>' + repo.description + '</div>';
      }

      markup += '</div></div>';

      return markup;
   }

   function repoFormatSelection(repo) {
      return repo.full_name;
   }
```